# Save/submit button when profile is set to "view"

Tags: wordpress, profile

One gets "Save" and "Cancel" buttons when adding a profile in "edit" mode. 
I'd like to see the same when presenting a profile in "view". Why? The client checks the entry and can then submit it - if changes have to be made, they go back to an editable profile page, just looks nicer in "view".
I've played around a bit with scripting - but no luck given little programming intelligence.
Any idea - this is all on a Wordpress platform.
Cheers

Comment: I've copied the form field code from an edit page - stripped it down - and changed the linked form = that worked. Will post as the code as an answer when time allows...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very non-coder way - I've got no real programming skills, so hacked around a bit - and maybe there are other ways of doing it better...

```
[civicrm component="profile" gid="yourvalue" mode="view" hijack="0"]

<form id="Edit" class="CRM_Profile_Form_Edit" action="http://yoururl/?page=CiviCRM&amp;q=civicrm/profile/edit" method="post" name="Edit" data-warn-changes="true">
<div>
<input name="entryURL" type="hidden" value="http://yoururl/?page=CiviCRM&amp;amp;q=civicrm/profile/edit&amp;amp;" />
<input name="gid" type="hidden" value="yourvalue" /> 
<input name="_qf_default" type="hidden" value="Edit:next" />
</div>
<div class="crm-container crm-submit-buttons">
<span class="crm-button crm-button-type-next crm-button_qf_Edit_next crm-icon-button"> 
<span class="crm-button-icon ui-icon-check"> 
</span> 
<input id="_qf_Edit_next" accesskey="S" class="crm-form-submit default validate" name="_qf_Edit_next" type="submit" value="Save and complete registration" />
</span>
</div>
```

Gives you->

[image]